# How to set a proxy for karate-jersey?

Tags: karate

I set proxy for apache in this way and it works:

```
* configure proxy = 'http://my.proxy.host:8080'
* configure ssl = true
```

But for Jersey it does not work. I tried to use karate.configure in `karate-config.js` but it also does not work for me.
How should I set a proxy for jersey?

Answer (score 1):

See if the info in this ticket helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/71

```
-DproxySet=true 
-DproxyHost=myhost.com
-DproxyPort=80
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.myhost.net|localhost|127.0.0.1"
```

Else, please open an issue following this process, it could be a bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue